# Blackberry 2D Game Engine Suggestions

Tags: blackberry, 2d

I am looking for 2D game engine for the Blackberry.  Any suggestions are appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You can also consider [V-Play](http://v-play.net/) (v-play.net) - a cross platform game engine based on Qt/QML (see the [API reference here](http://v-play.net/doc/vplay-group.html)). It added [official support for BlackBerry](http://v-play.net/2013/08/blackberry-10-support-in-v-play/) in August and also supports iOS, Android, Symbian, MeeGo and Desktop platforms.

V-Play also comes with ready-to-use game templates for the most successful game genres like tower defense, platform games or puzzle games, several tutorials and demos. ([V-Play examples & demos](http://v-play.net/doc/daily/))

V-Play was also featured on the BlackBerry Developers Blog recently [here](http://v-play.net/2013/08/gdc-europe-2013-highlights-blackberry-devblog-guest-post/#BB_DevBlog)

(Disclaimer: I'm one of the guys behind V-Play)

Answer (score 1):

I believe cocos2d has plans to support blackberry, but not yet more information here:

[cocos2d](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these engines:

- Gameplay - http://www.gameplay3d.org
- Linderdaum Engine - http://www.linderdaum.com

Answer (score 0):

To Update Oscar's point above, Cocos2d now supports blackberry ... 
You can find some simple steps in setting up a Cocos2dx for blackberry project here
http://denvycom.com/blog/setting-up-cocos2d-for-blackberry-10-development/

Answer (score 0):

You could try Oxygine 2D framework with Marmalade C++ SDK. 
http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/25580907/?countrycode=RU&lang=en